# Troubleshooting Assembled PCB

Tags: pcb, troubleshooting

I designed & assembled 3 copies of a circuit (BNO055 motion sensor board, used recommended i2c application from the datasheet).

1st one had some soldering issues, fixed them and it worked, received sensor data.
2nd one worked with no issues.
3rd is the culprit.

When I power the board everything looks fine, the ON led lights up, no smoke, no noise of any kind. The power supply shows 2mA current. But no data comes from the sensor.

Somewhere around 15th second the current starts to increase slowly. Around 20th second current reaches 10mA, after that within seconds the current reaches to 50mA and I cut the power, to protect the circuit.

I checked all the solder points, connector pins, etc. No bad solder, no short.

I connected the power again, same thing happened.

I wonder what would cause this behavior and how can I troubleshoot this problem.

I attached the schema & picture of the board

[image: Schema of the circuit]

[image: circuit board]

Comment: Is that the full schematic? I think I see more than two chips on that board but it only shows one in the diagram. Where is your sensor input? Is it pins 19 and 20? The labels are hard to read.

Comment: Eagle has a "Resolution" field when you export an image (assuming that's how you captured the schematic image). Increase the dpi value and repost the image. It's hard to read the fine print.

Comment: How much current do the other copies draw? Do you have an oscilloscope to check if there is signal in pin 27?

Comment: I added a better resolution image.

the other boards draw 2-3 mA current.

Comment: Check the polarity of any polarized caps (only C7?). That behavior sounds like a tantalum cap right before it exploded :)

Comment: only c7 is polarized and it is correct. other working 2 has the cap as same orientation

Comment: Wasn't SDA2 bridge touching a pad in SDA1? ALso, looks lie there's a solder blob under C7? Can you take a better (focused) picture of board?

Comment: the middle pins are already connected, bridge touching the other side would not matter. I checked C7's pins and they are connected.

Comment: Are you using an oscilloscope to troubleshoot?   presence of clock, etc.   It could be very helpful.